# How do I use "nanosleep" in x86 Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have some problems with Linux' nanosleep syscall. This code should wait 2 seconds before it exits, but it doesn't:

```
.text
.globl _start
_start:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp,%rbp        

pushq $0    #0 nanoseconds
pushq $2    #2 seconds

leaq (%rbp),%rdi    #the time structure on the stack       
movq $35,%rax       #nanosleep syscall
movq $0,%rsi        #disable useless parameter           
syscall             
leave
```

Comment: `int $0x80` is for making 32 bit system calls.  In 64 bit assembly, you should use 64 bit system calls which use different numbers and a different calling convention.  It is very much possible that your code doesn't work because the stack is not located within the first 4 GiB of address space.  If you use actual 64 bit system calls, it should work.

Comment: It doesnt work with "syscall" for me. See my edited code.

Comment: For future readers: this *was* a duplicate of [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code), but then the OP's edit to use `syscall` in response to comments changed it into a different question because it introduced a new bug: using `%rbp` instead of `%rsp` (as well as deleting the `sys_exit`, so this is now an incomplete code fragment...).  Anyway, this new question is the one that I answered; reopening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `push`ing stuff on the stack, use `mov %rsp, %rdi`.  **RSP (the current stack pointer) is what's pointing to your newly-pushed struct, not RBP (the frame pointer)**.  `lea (%rsp), %rdi` is a less-efficient way to write that, but would also work.

You're passing `RBP` as the pointer, but it still points to the saved RBP value from making a "stack frame".  Note that is `_start`, not a function, so you're really just terminating the linked list of saved-RBP values.  The System V ABI recommends doing this by explicitly setting RBP to zero, but Linux zeros registers (other than RSP) on process startup so this works.

Anyway, at `_start`, `(rsp)` is `argc`, and then you push a `0` (the saved RBP) and set RBP to point there.  So the struct you're passing to `sys_nanosleep` is `{0, argc}`.  Or `argc` nanoseconds.  (Test with `strace` to see if I got this right; I didn't try it.)

---

This is what you should do:

```
pushq $0    #0 nanoseconds
pushq $2    #2 seconds

### RSP instead of RBP in the next instruction:
mov   %rsp, %rdi    #the time structure we just pushed
mov   $35, %eax     #SYS_nanosleep
xor   %esi, %esi    #rem=NULL, we don't care if we wake early
syscall
 # RSP is 16 bytes lower than it was before this fragment, in case that matters for later code.
```

I also optimized by not using 64-bit operand-size when you don't need it (because writing a 32-bit register zeros the upper 32 bits). I like letting register sizes imply operand size instead of using `movq`, like in Intel syntax.  I also used the idiomatic way to zero a register, and improving the comments.

---

**Your proposed answer is broken**: `subq $16, %rbp` before `leave` is *bad* idea.

If you want to address your newly-pushed struct relative to your RBP stack frame, you could `lea -16(%rbp), %rdi`.

But modifying `%rbp` will make [`leave`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/LEAVE) set `RSP` to the updated `RBP` and then pop the low qword of the struct into `RBP`, instead of the caller's saved `RBP`.  RSP is left pointing to the high qword of your struct, rather than the function return address.

This probably only works because you just use `sys_exit` after `leave`, because you're not in a function so you couldn't `ret` anyway.  It makes no sense to use `leave` in `_start`, because it's not a function.  You have to just `sys_exit` or `sys_exit_group`.

But if you used this fragment inside an actual function, it would break the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on myself. This works:

```
#call nanosleep    
movq $35,%rax
subq $16, %rbp
movq %rbp,%rdi  
movq $0,%rsi          
syscall             
leave
```

Comment: You're making this overcomplicated:  after the `push`es, `mov %rsp, %rdi`.  RSP (the current stack pointer) is what's pointing to your newly-pushed struct, not the frame pointer.  `lea -16(%rbp), %rdi` would also work, but **modifying `%rbp` before `leave` is a *bad* idea**.  That will set `RSP` to the updated `RBP` and then pop the struct into `RBP`, instead of the caller's saved `RBP`.  This probably only works because you don't actually `ret` anywhere, and just use `sys_exit` after `leave`.